# Google base layer opacity change in OpenLayers 2.13

Tags: openlayers-2

I have recently swapped from using OpenLayers 2.12 to 2.13.1 as it fixes a bug. However in 2.12 I was using a base layer opacity of 0.7 to 'knock back' the map so that the vector layers stood out more, but this doesn't work in 2.13. In 2.13 OpenLayers the base layer opacity on a Google map is applied to all layers, so this trick doesn't work. I believe this is because 2.13 changes how Google base layers are handled (see [release notes](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/notes/2.13.md)).

Anyone have a suggested work round that will work in OpenLayers 2.13.1? i.e. I want to make the map layer more transparent/less contrast while keeping the vector layers at full contrast so they stand out.

Also I am testing with Google but may go with a different map provider in the final application, due to licencing costs, so a generic answer for any base map type would be helpful.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hello Jon. I am the problem persists. I still can't set the opacity in an OpenLayers.Layer.Google. I created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/joaorodr84/pen/PqaEww) to illustrate the issue. Meanwhile, have you found a solution for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hi joaorodr84. Sorry, but I didn't find a solution for Google. In the end I needed to swap to  OpemStreetMaps anyway and I found that the `OpenLayers.Layer.OSM` layer create method takes an `opacity` property in the setting. That worked a treat and allowed me to 'knock back' the map layer.

Comment: OK. So you stopped using Google layer and started using OSM layer. If I find a solution for this, I will post it here. Thanks anyway. :)